# Excel 2010: Giving another cell value to an "x" (check) in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Hopefully I'll be able to explain clearly what I would like:

I have a spreadsheet about a car pool. I have to put an "x" (check) in a cell when there are seats available to transport people, but I want this "x" to have a value from another cell:

[image: Screenshot of spredsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in `G28` Cell, which gives `x` as result:-

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G3:G27, "=x")>0, "x", "")
```

If you want count of those cells then use this formula:-

```
=SUMIF(G3:G27, "=x",D3:D27)
```

If your sheet popup for Circular Reference, then you need to enable Circular Reference. Below are the steps:-

1. Click on **Office Button**
2. Click **Excel Options** Link
3. Click **Formula** Link from Left Navigation
4. Check the **Enable Iterative Calculation** box
5. Click **OK** button

Now you will result as `10` in `G28` Cell

Comment: Don't understand the point about circular reference @Siva_Charan, can't you just use the SUMIF as a regular formula? In G28 copied across `=SUMIF(G3:G27,"x",$D3:$D27)`

Comment: @barryhoudini: When am testing with inputs, I have common across with a popup related to circular reference thats the reason I have given steps. Actually I don't think circular reference is required for **SUMIF**. Thanks for pointing.